# How to get Contents section data from some Wikipedia page?

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata

I am looking for a `dump file` (ideally) or an `API` call to get the Contents section of Wikipedia pages.  e.g.  [Fitbit page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitbit)

[image: Fitbit content]

Any help really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) by parsing the page. For your example the query will be:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=sections&page=Fitbit
```

Response will include all page sections with their names (**line**s) and heading **level**s.

```
{
    "parse": {
        "sections": [
            {
                "index": "1",
                "line": "Products",
                "level": "2",
                ...
            },
            {
                "index": "2",
                "line": "Fitbit Tracker",
                "level": "3",
                ...
            },
            {
                "index": "3",
                "line": "Fitbit Ultra",
                "level": "3",
                ...
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: forgot to thank you Termininja for your answer. I was more keen on using a dump file as takes far less time, but it seems API is the only solution here. Thanks !